# How to stop sed from inserting newline?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line

I want to stop `sed` from adding a newline with the `i` editing command:

```
>echo "hello" | sed 'i TEST'
TEST
hello
```

The result I want is:

```
TESThello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible. Do it this way instead:

```
sed 's/^/TEST/' file
```

Comment: seems like the `i` and `a` commands can be replaced by `s` most of the times.

Comment: @Pedro They have different purposes. `i` and `a` are to insert and append complete lines before/after the current line. `s` is to make substitutions in the current pattern buffer. There's also `c` that works like `a` and `i`, but replaces ("changes") the whole current line.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this too:

```
echo "hello" | sed "s/$/TEST/"
```

What it is doing is replacing the end of the line (/$/) with the text you want.